# Why does my slider value not change to 50 when moving it with Tricentis Tosca?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, testing, slider, tosca

I want to use with Tricentis Tosca this slide function from the https://letcode.in/slider website. I can move the slide to the right, but the value of 10 does not change to 50. With Selenium it worked, I could then click the button and verify all 50 countries. With Tosca the slide goes to the right, but the value at the top stays at 10 and I can only select 10 countries.

I use with Tosca this guide https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1520/en/content/tbox/type_slider.htm

but it did not help.
Does anyone have any better advice?

I simply moved the slider according to the instructions, but it did not change the value

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: read this [ask]

Answer (score 0):

It is not always 50, i had a slider from value 0 to 4. You also have to put a businessparameter min and max to module